# c# IEnumerable double iteration

Tags: c#, ienumerable

This is out of curiosity I want to ask this question...

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count - 1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < myList.Count; ++j)
    {
        DoMyStuff(myList[i], myList[j]);
    }
}
```

Pretty simple loop, but obviously it only works with List...
But I was wondering... how can I code this loop in order to make it independent of the collection's type (deriving from IEnumerable...)
My first thought:

```
IEnumerator it1 = myList.GetEnumerator();
while (it1.MoveNext())
{
    IEnumerator it2 = it1; // this part is obviously wrong
    while (it2.MoveNext())
    {
        DoMyStuff(it1.Current, it2.Current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because enumerators don't have an efficient way of getting the n'th element, your best bet is to copy the enumerable into a list, then use your existing code:

```
void CrossMap<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    List<T> myList = enumerable.ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < myList.Count; ++j)
        {
            DoMyStuff(myList[i], myList[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is a rather tricksie hack you can do with some collection types. Because the enumerators of some of the collection types in the BCL are declared as value types, rather than reference types, you can create an implicit clone of the state of an enumerator by copying it to another variable:

```
// notice the struct constraint!
void CrossMap<TEnum, T>(TEnum enumerator) where TEnum : struct, IEnumerator<T>
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        TEnum enum2 = enumerator;    // value type, so this makes an implicit clone!
        while (enum2.MoveNext())
        {
            DoMyStuff(enumerator.Current, enum2.Current);
        }
    }
}

// to use (you have to specify the type args exactly)
List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
CrossMap<List<int>.Enumerator, int>(list.GetEnumerator());
```

This is quite obtuse, and quite hard to use, so you should only do this if this is performance and space-critical.

Comment: I would suggest using `Array` instead of `List`.

Comment: If you're going to change the type, you might as well change it to an array instead of a list. Less memory, and quicker access.

Comment: I prefer to use `List<T>` rather than an array. `ToArray` requires an array the exact size of the enumerable, whereas `ToList` just puts all the elements in a list. This requires extra copying. Check the implementation of `System.Linq.Buffer`

Comment: Your second solution is what I was looking for, thanks. I guess I didn't ask the good question, which should be: Why can't we easily clone IEnumerator? And I found a few posts talking about that...

Comment: @s0ubap: Because it's simply not part of the contract of `IEnumerator` - it doesn't have a method declared on the interface to clone it. You could check whether the enumerator implements `ICloneable` (like `Array`'s enumerator does), but there's no standard way of cloning an enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

There are extension methods `Count()` and `ElementAt(int)` that are declared on `IEnumerable<T>`. They are declared in the `System.Linq` namespace, which should be included by default in your .cs files if you are using any C# version later than C# 3. That means that you could you just do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count() - 1; ++i)
{
  for (int j = i+1; j < myList.Count(); ++j)
  {
    DoMyStuff(myList.ElementAt(i), myList.ElementAt(j));
  }
}
```

However, note that these are methods, and will be called over and over again during iteration, so you might want to save their result to variables, like:

```
var elementCount = myList.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < elementCount - 1; ++i)
{
  var iElement = myList.ElementAt(i);
  for (int j = i+1; j < elementCount; ++j)
  {
    DoMyStuff(iElement, myList.ElementAt(j));
  }
}
```

You could also try some LINQ that will select all pair of elements that are eligible, and then use simple `foreach` to call the processing, something like:

```
var result = myList.SelectMany((avalue, aindex) => 
               myList.Where((bvalue, bindex) => aindex < bindex)
                     .Select(bvalue => new {First = avalue, Second = bvalue}));

foreach (var item in result)
{
  DoMyStuff(item.First, item.Second);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that will truly use the lazy `IEnumerable` paradigm to generate a stream of non-duplicated combinations from a single `IEnumerable` input. The first pair will return immediately (no cacheing of lists), but there will be increasing delays (still imperceptible except for very high values of n or very expensive `IEnumerable`s) during the `Skip(n)` operation which occurs after every move forward on the outer enumerator:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Combinate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
    var outer = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    var n = 1;
    while (outer.MoveNext()) {
        foreach (var item in enumerable.Skip(n))
            yield return Tuple.Create(outer.Current, item);
        n++;
    }
}
```

Here is how you would use it in your case:

```
foreach(var pair in mySource.Combinate())
    DoMyStuff(pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
```

**Postscript**

Everyone has pointed out (here and elsewhere) that there is no efficient way of getting the "nth" element of an `IEnumerable`. This is partly because `IEnumerable` does not require there to even be an underlying source collection. For example, here's a silly little function that that dynamically generates values for an experiment as quickly as they can be consumed, and continues for a specified period of *time* rather than for any count:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> Sample(double milliseconds, Func<double> generator) {
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds);
    sw.Start();
    while (sw.Elapsed < timeout)
        yield return generator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write against `IEnumerable<T>` and pass a delegate for the indexing operation:

```
public static void DoStuff<T>(IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<int, T> selector)
{
    int count = seq.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < count; ++j)
        {
            DoMyStuff(selector(i), selector(j));
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it using:

```
List<T> list = //whatever
DoStuff(list, i => list[i]);
```

If you restrict the collection argument to `ICollection<T>` you can use the `Count` property instead of using the `Count()` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Not really efficient, but readable:

```
int i = 0;
foreach( var item1 in myList)
{
    ++i;
    foreach( var item2 in myList.Skip(i))
        DoMyStuff(item1, item2);
}
```

Comment: Argh you beat me by a minute. :) I think this approach is likely to be fastest for smaller lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it fairly succinctly using IEnumerable.Skip(), and it might even be fairly fast compared with copying the list into an array IF the list is short enough. It's bound to be a lot slower than the copying for lists of a sufficient size, though.

You'd have to do some timings with lists of various sizes to see where copying to an array becomes more efficient.

Here's the code. Note that it's iterating an enumerable twice - which will be ok if the enumerable is implemented correctly!

```
static void test(IEnumerable<int> myList)
{
    int n = 0;

    foreach (int v1 in myList)
    {
        foreach (int v2 in myList.Skip(++n))
        {
            DoMyStuff(v1, v2);
        }
    }
}
```